# How to export a balkan graph to pdf and png?

Tags: export, orgchart

I worked on an organisation chart Project, and I want to export that chart to pdf and png files. I read the BALKAN GRAPH documentation https://balkangraph.com/OrgChartJS/Docs/Exporting but i did not understand how to fill the exportURL option.
Please give me an example of it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

BALKANGraph developer evangelist here

First you have to install your own export server

You can download export server from https://balkangraph.com/console

Then change exportUrl option to point to you export server

```
   var chart = new OrgChart(document.getElementById("tree"), {
        exportUrl: "https://[yourserver]/export",
        ...
   });
```

Where [yourserver] could be a domain name or IP address

Comment: I clicked on GO TO CONSOLE, but how can i register?

Comment: If you are not a customer you need to buy a license

Comment: i send you an email, please check